# Loopback : Making synchronous call to loopback api

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I want to make a synchronous call to one of the APIs that i have designed using loopback. Here is my code :

```
router.get('/friends', function(req, res, Array) {
    var friendsList = []
    for(var counter=0;counter<length;counter++){
                  Model.findById(Array[counter].Id,function(err, record) {
                    if(record){
                        friendsList.push(record);
                    }
                  });
                }
                res.status(200).json(friendsList);
});
```

Now im getting the response before the array, **friendList** is getting populated completely. I want to make this synchronous and get the correct response. What should i do?

Thanks!

Comment: you can't make a synchronous call to an asynchronous function

Comment: Stick the `res.json` inside the callback?

Comment: @tymeJV - that wont work, because the callback could be (probably is if you look at the code) called multiple times

Comment: @JaromandaX -- Ahh yeah.. should've looked closer, thought the `for` was after the DB call :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a simplistic way to do it is

- set a variable to `length`
- every time the callback is called, decrease this variable by 1
- when it reaches zero, you've processed the final callback
- WITHIN the callback, call `res.status...`

Like this:

```
router.get('/friends', function(req, res, array) {
    var friendsList = [];
    var remaining = length;
    for(var counter=0;counter<length;counter++){
        Model.findById(array[counter].Id, function(err, record) {
            if (record){
                friendsList.push(record);
            }
            remaining -= 1;
            if (remaining == 0) {
                res.status(200).json(friendsList);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

for completeness ... since you're using nodejs ... use (native) Promise and `arrow function` syntax

```
router.get('/friends', (req, res, array) =>
    Promise.all(array.map(item => 
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
            Model.findById(item.Id, (err, record) => 
                resolve(record || undefined)
            )
        )
    ))
    .then(friendsList => 
        res.status(200).json(friendsList.filter(item => 
            item !== undefined
        ))
    )
);
```

Comment: The promise way isn't synchronous for me in node v9.2.0

Comment: "the promise way" isn't synchronous anywhere - promises are inherently asynchronous. Considering `Model.findById` is already asynchronous, there's no way to get a synchronous result

Comment: @JaromandaX my bad, it was a syntax error. I wasn't returning the new Promise().

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `async` and `underscore` modules

```
var async = require('async');
var _ = require('underscore');

router.get('/friends', function(req, res, Array) {
    var friendsList = [];
    var waterfallFunctions = [];
    _.each(Array, function(element) {
      waterfallFunctions.push( function(next) {
        Model.findById(element.Id,function(err, record) {
          if (err) return next(err);

          if(record){
            friendsList.push(record);
          }

          next();
        });
      });
    });

    //async waterfall calls the functions in the array in order.
    async.waterfall(waterfallFunctions, function (err) {
      if (err) return res.status(500);

      res.status(200).json(friendsList);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Promises and the `$in` operator in Mongoose:

```
router.get('/friends', function(req, res, arr) {
    var promise = Model.find({ _id: { $in: arr.slice(0, length).map(function (e) { return e.Id }) } }).exec()
    promise.then(function (friendsList) {
        res.status(200).json(friendsList)
    })
})
```

`arr.slice` picks the first `length` elements from the array.  `Model.find` creates a single query, which is more efficient than performing multiple `findById` queries.  The `$in` operator accepts an array of ids to do a look-up against.  `.exec()` creates a single promise, which is resolved with `.then(...)`.

Comment: how does `Model.find` know to look for `Id` in each array item? should there be a map perhaps in there? Also, what makes you think mongoose is involved? (not saying you're wrong, just can't see any mention of it until you posted the answer)

Comment: The `$in` operator accepts an array of ids.  I assumed Mongoose because of the syntax used.  However, most modern ORMs support some notion of multiple object look-ups and promises.  For ORMs other than Mongoose, appropriate API calls may be used.

Comment: You missed the point of my question. The original code suggests `array` is an array of `objects` that have a property `Id` - your code does not seem to pass an array of `Id` it passes (a copy of) the original array of objects

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  Will have to stick a map in there after all.

Comment: no need to slice with a map, is there? `$in: arr.map(e => e.Id )` (using arrow functions, it is nodejs after all)

Comment: Original code only picks the first `length` elements from `arr`.

Comment: ahhh yes, seeing as it isn't passed in as an argument, nor is it declared anywhere else, I assumed it was simply "missing code" - I'd hate to think it was a global variable!

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until the N findById calls finish so a solution is make an array of promises and use the Promise.all method.

```
router.get('/friends', function(req, res, Array) {
    var friendsList = []
    var friendsPromises = []

    for (var counter=0; counter<length; counter++) {
        var friend = Model.findById(Array[counter].Id;
        friendsList.push(friend)

        friend.then(function(record) {
            if (record) {
                friendsList.push(record);
            }
        })
    }

    Promise.all(friendsPromises).then(function(){
        res.status(200).json(friendsList);    
    })
});
```